# Is there any way to lock down an ssh private key so that it can be used, but not read/copied?

Tags: macos, unix, ssh, private-key

I need to make a private key (.pem file) available for a user to connect via ssh (they're using a Mac), however we need to prevent the key from being physically readable by that user. Is this possible?

Comment: Obviously not, reading is reading. The question is: why don't you create a separate key for that user, so you stay in control? And why that user should not "read" the key?

Comment: If you're using private keys then the user should have their own. It's called a "key exchange"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store them on the Smart Card or some equivalent (Yubikey, HSM, or so). You can safely generate the key on the card, protect usage by PIN and do not allow reading it. OpenSSH supports using authentication keys from smart cards using PKCS#11 interface. OpenSC library to access them works fine on both linux and OSX.